# How to delete dollar signs($) from a PHP variable only if the dollar signs are surrounding a word

Tags: php

I want to delete any dollar sign($) from a PHP variable **only** if it surrounds a word.

I know how to replace every $ with empty space to look like is deleted, for example:

```
  <?php 

      $string = 'Hello $George$';
      $string = str_replace('$', '', $string);
      echo $string; // Prints: Hello George


   ?>
```

But the code above is also removing $ that are not surrounding a word, for example:

```
<?php 

      $string = 'Hello $George$, are you $ok?';
      $string = str_replace('$', '', $string);
      echo $string; // Prints Hello George, are you ok?

   ?>
```

I've been trying for many hours to solve this problem but didn't manage to puzzle it out, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how it would replace the $ from $ok in `$string = "Hello $George$, are you $ok?";`  ... because it would actually already have replaced $ok with the value of that variable while it was assigning it to $string.

Comment: Simple comment answer will probably follow by someone else but simple. Use Regular Expressions to "match" the beginning and ending "$" symbols.

Comment: as another recommendation when setting your strings use SINGLE QUOTE ' to prevent php from attmepting to parse the $string as a variable

Comment: Unless you meant to write: `$string = 'Hello $George$, are you $ok?';` (note the single quotes)... but then you'd end up having to `eval()` that string to get $ok to replace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First of all, i will answer your question**

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead, that is uses with a pattern that detects only those dollar signs, that are surrounding a word.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\$(\w+)\$/', '$1', $string);
```

**Now an improvement for your code**

As mentioned in the comments of your question, you would need to surround your string with single quotes (`'`) to prevent PHP from replacing your words, that are prefixed by a dollar sign, with their corresponding variables.

A good source to understand the differences between double- and single-enquoted strings can be found [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/8913537).